# ¿Como contar proyectos en su estado de operación relacionado a un fondo en SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

`

```
SELECT DEPENDENCIA.CODICLASIF AS "ID_REGION",DEPENDENCIA.DESCRIBECO AS "NOM_REGION",CAT_FONDOS.CVE_FONDO,DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO,DEF_EDOS.DESCRIBE as "DESCRIBE_EDO"
FROM REGPOAD --TABLA PROYECTOS  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASIPOA CODADMI ON (CODADMI.T_OPCLAS = 'ANTEP') AND CODADMI.CVEANTEPRO = REGPOAD.CVEANTEPRO AND CODADMI.CVE_POA = REGPOAD.CVE_POA AND CODADMI.PERIODO = REGPOAD.PERIODO AND CODADMI.ID=2--ID REGION  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASMULT DEPENDENCIA ON DEPENDENCIA.CODICLASIF = SUBSTRING(CODADMI.CODICLASIF,1,7)+REPLICATE('0',7) --DESCRIPCION REGION 
LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF_EDOS ON (DEF_EDOS.TIPO_OPE = 'POA' AND DEF_EDOS.ID_TASK = REGPOAD.ID_TASK AND DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO = REGPOAD.ID_ESTADO)--TABLA ESTADOS
LEFT OUTER JOIN CAT_FONDOS ON CAT_FONDOS.CVE_FONDO = REGPOAD.CVE_FONDO--FONDOS DEL PROYECTO
```

`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Imagen de ejemplo de como se deveria visualizar la contabilización de los proyectos por fondo en su estado de operación correspondiente

Comment: ¿Y el código que ya tenías? Estaba muy cercano a ser correcto, solo necesitaba unos ajustes.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Como mínimo necesitamos la estructura de las tablas involucradas

Comment: Las anexo en un momento ya que son algo extensas, trataré de compartir lo necesario

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas es un agregado condicional o pivote. Personalmente, no me gusta el comando `PIVOT` y por eso sugiero el agregado condicional que es más flexible.

Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como quedaría. Usamos CASE para regresar 1 o nulo. La funciones de agregado ignoran el nulo por eso no lo cuentan. El 1 se puede reemplazar por cualquier valor ya que solo sirve para que se cuente la fila.

```
SELECT D.CODICLASIF AS [ID_REGION],
       D.DESCRIBECO AS [NOM_REGION],
       F.CVE_FONDO,
       COUNT( CASE WHEN P.ID_ESTADO = 1 THEN 1 END) AS [ELABORACION],
       COUNT( CASE WHEN P.ID_ESTADO = 2 THEN 1 END) AS [Enviado a la UR],
       COUNT( CASE WHEN P.ID_ESTADO = 3 THEN 1 END) AS [Autorizado por la UR],
       COUNT( CASE WHEN P.ID_ESTADO = 4 THEN 1 END) AS [Autorizado por SAF]
FROM REGPOAD P --TABLA PROYECTOS  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASIPOA A   ON A.CVEANTEPRO = P.CVEANTEPRO 
                            AND A.CVE_POA    = P.CVE_POA 
                            AND A.PERIODO    = P.PERIODO 
                            AND A.T_OPCLAS   = 'ANTEP'
                            AND A.ID         = 2--ID REGION  
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASMULT D   ON D.CODICLASIF = SUBSTRING(A.CODICLASIF,1,7)+REPLICATE('0',7) --DESCRIPCION REGION 
--La tabla de estados no es necesaria
--LEFT OUTER JOIN DEF_EDOS E   ON E.ID_TASK    = P.ID_TASK 
--                            AND E.ID_ESTADO  = P.ID_ESTADO 
--                            AND E.TIPO_OPE   = 'POA' --TABLA ESTADOS
LEFT OUTER JOIN CAT_FONDOS F ON F.CVE_FONDO  = P.CVE_FONDO --FONDOS DEL PROYECTO
GROUP BY D.CODICLASIF,
       D.DESCRIBECO,
       F.CVE_FONDO;
```

Comment: Ya lo resolví, CASE WHEN DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS ELABORACION, CASE WHEN DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS "EVIADO_UR", CASE WHEN DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS "AUTORIZA_UR", CASE WHEN DEF_EDOS.ID_ESTADO = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END  AS "AUTORIZA_SAF" todo esto mas las tablas del from y union las meti en otro FROM y en el SELECT solo sume el campo asi SUM(TABLA.ELABORACION) as "TOT_ELABORA" asi con cada uno y lo agrupe por región y fondo GROUP BY TABLA.REGION,TABLA.CVE_FONDO, gracias por la ayuda de todos modos...